# Custom local gem: Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-your-first-gem/) while creating my first Ruby gem. At the end of step 4 described there, there's a file `my_gem-0.0.0.gem`. For the time being, I'd like to keep this gem locally, so I tried putting it in a `gems` directory at the root of my rails project.

In the `Gemfile` I added this line:

```
gem 'my_gem', path: 'gems'
```

We use Docker, and when I try starting this container, I see my new gem is not found:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem 'my_gem' in the source at `gems`
The source does not contain any versions of 'my_gem'
```

I tried adding/removing the `gem` extension and the `-0.0.1` part both in the filename and in the `Gemfile`, but nothing worked. What's wrong here?

Comment: Can you try giving `path` the path to the gem folder, e.g. `path: "gems/my_gem"`? Also have you verified that the `gems/` folder is present on the docker build?

Comment: The path from my code seems to be correct. When I change it, the error message changes to `path [...] does not exist`. I suspect it might be a problem with Docker as I realized I can do `gem install --local /var/workdir/gems/my_gem-0.0.1.gem` inside the container while `RUN gem install --local /var/workdir/gems/my_gem-0.0.1.gem` in a `Dockerfile` results in a similar error as above.

Answer (score 0):

To works with Docker you need to clone the repository from github to your custom folder. In example below the steps to reproduce how I use custom path to edit gems in a separeted folder:

1. In my local machine I use a **/gems** folder inside **my rails application folder**: `mkdir <my-app>/gems`.
2. `cd <my-app>/gems`.
3. `git clone <gem-repository-source>`. Is necessary to clone because if you copy from other folder in your computer probably some files are missed.
4. Set in your **Gemfile**: `gem '<gem-name>', path: '/bundle/custom_gems/<gem-name>'`.
5. If you use docker-compose, you need to bind folders with **volumes** config, like below:

```
volumes:
    - ./app/gems:/bundle/custom_gems
```

With this, your local folder (your machine) copy files inside **./app/gems** to **/bundle/custom_gems** in Docker container.

6. Restart service.

If you **NOT** use docker-compose, you need add in Dockerfile some like:
`ADD ./app/gems /bundle/custom_gems`